# Draw rectangles on an image within for loop

Tags: matlab, drawing, rectangles

I would like to draw rectangles on an image in MATLAB. In every iteration I need to draw new rectangles and delete the previous ones.

I read the image once, and then draw the rectangles in a for loop, using

```
rectangle('Position',[boxPoint(1),boxPoint(2),24,32],'LineWidth',1, 'EdgeColor','g');
```

However, in every iteration, the rectangles are drawn on top of the old ones. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: That's great. What have you tried so far to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

The `rectangle` function can return a handle which you can subsequently use to delete it:

```
% Draw figure with 2 rectangles
h = figure;
hold on
xlim([0,100])
ylim([0,100])
r(1) = rectangle('Position', [10,10,10,10]); % Make sure keep handles to rectangles
r(2) = rectangle('Position', [50,50,10,10]);

delete(r(1)) % Delete a rectangle
```

Comment: Or you can use the handle to move the rectangle to a new position: `r(1).set('Position',[50,50,10,10]);`

Comment: I did something similar to what you did
for i=1:total
r(i) = rectangle('Position', [10,10,10,10]); 
end
Then I tried to delete(r) later in the code but the rectangles were not deleted also!

Comment: You might need to give the index of the rectangle you wish to delete, i.e. `delete(r(i))`.

Comment: Alternatively, try telling Matlab to redraw using `drawnow` or `refresh`.